# URI works in a SPARQL query, but the Namespace does not

Tags: namespaces, uri, sparql

I am querying the [NIFSTD](https://github.com/SciCrunch/NIF-Ontology) ontology. I have loaded it into [Fuseki](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/), a local triple store/ sparql server.

When querying for the synonyms of the 'hippocampus', the below code with the namespace does not return any answers:

```
prefix nifstdr: <http://uri.neuinfo.org/nif/nifstd/readable>
prefix rdf: <...>
.
.   
SELECT distinct ?s ?synonyms
    {?s rdfs:label "Hippocampus" ;
        nifstd:synonym ?synonyms .}
```

While using the URI works and returns correct answers:

```
prefix rdfs: ...    
prefix rdf: ...

SELECT distinct ?s ?synonyms
    {?s rdfs:label "Hippocampus" ;
        <http://uri.neuinfo.org/nif/nifstd/readable/synonym> ?synonyms .}
```

Another similar (but opposite) instance to this one was when I was querying the local graph for IDs of the concepts as below:

```
PREFIX oboInOwl: <http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#>
select distinct ?id
where{
  graph <http://localhost:3030/myDataset/data/nif>{
  ?s oboInOwl:id ?id.  
  }
}
limit 100
```

This code returned results.

However, using URI within the code as below, returned no results at all!

```
select distinct ?id
where{
  graph <http://localhost:3030/myDataset/data/nif>{
  ?s <http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl/id> ?id.  
  }
}
limit 100
```

So, this time it was the other way around!

I thought maybe this is because the local triple store has a URI that I previously used for this dataset in its cache, so I gave it a different name, but the problem still persists.

Why does this happen?

Comment: what means "does not work"?

Comment: No answer is returned. BTW, thank you for your previous answer. I deleted that post since I realized my mistake was very basic and the post served no purpose to other new sparql users like me.

Comment: In general, prefix declarations have to be put in the beginning of the SPARQL query, i.e. `PREFIX  nifstd: <http://uri.neuinfo.org/nif/nifstd/readable/> SELECT ...` - anything beyond is not part of the SPARQL standard and just a matter of the triple store configuration. Clearly, adding it to the SPARQL query is the better way as this makes the query self-contained and processable on any other SPARQL engine.

Comment: @AKSW I didn't know that! I thought using prefixes is better since makes the code more readable! Also, there are  at least around 10 URI's for NIF. I realized this one is relocated physically, but on their files, they have not changed the URIs! I was even a little bit surprised when I saw this uri works! Do different URIs work for a dataset that has been loaded on a different place until their structure remains the same?

Comment: Of course it makes it more readable, but mostly only when you use URIs from the namespace multiple times. On the other hand, it's still a more compact SPARQL query body and one could ignore the prefixes if the goal is just to understand the query.

Comment: I cannot follow you with the other questions, but in Fuseki I guess you can add more prefixes in the config file. You know, this Turtle file where you set up all the services etc. : https://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/fuseki-configuration.html

Comment: Fuseki requires queries to be complete (with any PREFIX needed) - it does not add prefixes.

Comment: @AndyS Thanks. Of course, I use Fuseki as a standalone server and can use prefixes by defining them on top of the query as other sparql servers and endpoints. Maybe the way I asked this questions made confusions. I edited it.

Comment: I've updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the updated question,

The full URI in the query is `http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl/id` 
but `oboInOwl:id` expands to a different URI: `http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#id`

The difference is the  `#`-`/` .

`nifstd:synonym` becomes `http://uri.neuinfo.org/nif/nifstd/readablesynomyn` not `.../readable/synomyn`.

Comment: Thank you! And do we always have to have the `#` at the end of URIs used in ontologies? I mean do we have something like: `http://ontologyAddress/#` ?

Comment: It is whatever the ontology defines - ending in "#" or "/" are common patterns but not required. A "prefixed name" is turned into a URI by concatenating the URI in the prefix declaration with the local name,nothing more.